# Filtering and deleting attribute table on multiple shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, fields-attributes

In QGIS 3.22 I have about 30 thousand objects (rows) on several vectors (shp) and I want to filter my table to keep only some objects and delete the rest.

[image]

How can I do it in a simple operation?

Comment: By selecting and deleting them. If you want a more specific answer, you need to be more specific yourself.

Comment: I modified my answer, I have to delete thousands of objects for multiple layers that have codes between X and X, how I am supposed todo that?

Comment: Are you asking how to select integer values of a specific range?

Comment: Basically I have 30 thousands objects and I want to keep only the one with a specific codes and delete all the other one

Comment: Do you know how to use [`select by expression`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#automatic-selection)?

Comment: Whenever "and" is used in the title, a Question is vulnerable to closure for being *too broad*. In this case, the two steps requested are the two steps required. It seems simple enough, so what exactly are you asking for in a "simple solution"? Deleting features is always risky, so I prefer to select the features I want to keep, and save those to a new file but it remains a two-step process. Have you tried either and encountered an error? If so, *that* would be an appropriate topic for a Question.

Comment: Dear Vince, thank you for your reply! maybe I can just filter my attribute table and thus I could make my calculations without deleting ?